# How to display dynamically generated <select> in a row on a same line?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I need to dynamically display the list of ingredients in a row of 3 columns, but I've got the problem that my output isn't aligned on a row. Can anyone help with the solution, It may look a little complicated, but I am getting desperate already.

```
function display(){
var lght = jsn[0].ingredient.length; 
var old_val = new Array(lght);
var ell =  "";
var ul = document.getElementById("comp_tag");
for(let a=0; a < lght; a++){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var divr = document.createElement('div');
    li.setAttribute("id","lineid_"+a);
    divr.setAttribute("class","row align-middle");
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(divr);
    var col_one = document.createElement('div');
    col_one.setAttribute("class","col-6 text-left");
    col_one.setAttribute("id","col1"+a);
    divr.appendChild(col_one);
    col_one.appendChild(document.createTextNode("value 1"));
    var col_two = document.createElement('div');
    col_two.setAttribute("class","col-3 text-right");
    col_two.setAttribute("id","col2"+a);
    divr.appendChild(col_two);
    col_two.appendChild(document.createTextNode("value 2"));
    var col_three = document.createElement('div');
    col_three.setAttribute("class","col-3 text-left");
    col_three.setAttribute("id","col3"+a);
    divr.appendChild(col_three);
    var pb = init_workspace(jsn[0].ingredient[a].type);
    var sel = document.createElement("select");
    sel.setAttribute("class","custom-select");
    sel.setAttribute("id","c_select"+a);
    col_three.appendChild(sel);
    for(var t=0; t<pb.length; t++){
        var optn = document.createElement("option");
        if(jsn[0].ingredient[a].unit == pb[t].name){
            optn.setAttribute("selected","")
        };
        optn.setAttribute("value",pb[t].name);
        sel.appendChild(optn);
        optn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pb[t].name));
    }
```

And my HTML part is:

```
<div class="col-md text-right" id="divid">
        <p class="text-uppercase"><b>ingredients</b></p>
        <ul id="comp_tag">
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the created `<li>` tags to be inline, have you tried making your UL tag a flex container `display: flex;`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `jsn` object? And update the javascript so it's valid, it's missing some `}`.

Comment: Without the jsn object and its structure it is tough recreating your display. Also it seems you have left off two closing parenthesis in your function.

Comment: Yeah, it's surely my fault. I thought including it will just make the code horribly unreadable, I need to be a lot more attentive to the code I post. But the advice was useful adding display: flex; fixed my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With out the jsn object to recreate this example as you would see it, I am supplying a static example below...

Make the parent element of your list items a flex container. This will place the block level items in a row. To illustrate this I have placed static list items within a UL and targeted it using CSS `display: flex;`.

```css
#divid #comp_tag {
  display: flex;
}
```

Following is a very simple snippit that recreates an object and places the objects items in a row using `display:flex` on the parent UL element.

Hope this helps...

```js
let obj = {
  0: {
    'name': 'Cajun Delight',
    'ingredients': {
      'type': {
        'salt': '1 teaspoon',
        'garlic': '2 cloves',
        'pepper': '1 pinch'
      }
    }
  },
  1: {
    'name': 'Midwest Bland',
    'ingredients': {
      'type': {
        'salt': '1 teaspoon',
        'garlic': '2 cloves',
        'pepper': '1 pinch'
      }
    }
  },
  2: {
    'name': 'Asian Stir Fry',
    'ingredients': {
      'type': {
        'salt': '1 teaspoon',
        'garlic': '3 cloves',
        'pepper': '1 pinch',
        'soy_sauce': '1/4 cup'
      }
    }
  }
}


function displayInfo() {
  let compTag = document.getElementById("comp_tag");
  for (let values in obj) {
    let li = document.createElement("LI");
    li.textContent = obj[values].name;
    compTag.append(li);
    compTag.style.justifyContent = "space-around";

    if (obj[values].ingredients.type) {
      for (let type in obj[values].ingredients.type) {
        let subUl = document.createElement("UL");
        let subLi = document.createElement("LI");
        li.append(subUl);
        subUl.append(subLi);
        subLi.textContent = `${obj[values].ingredients.type[type]}`;        
      }

    }

  }
}

displayInfo();
```

```css
#divid #comp_tag {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md text-right" id="divid">
        <p class="text-uppercase"><b>ingredients</b></p>
        <ul id="comp_tag">
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding flex attribute solved the case! Sorry for not attaching jsn object.